# Using Div's and .load to show images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ms-access, coldfusion

How would I get this code to show an image? I was using iFrame's but was told if I ultimately want to link text with each picture that using Div's and .load would be better. I cant seem to get anything to load though using Div's.

......

This what I have now as of Dec 26, 2013

I have been able to incorporate all of the info I have learned so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <cfquery datasource="AccessTest" name="qTest">
        SELECT Account, Image, Image_ID
        FROM PictureDB
    </cfquery>
```

SELECT Accounts, Remarks, Users, Image_ID
    FROM CommentPicture

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"> </script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    var images = {

    <cfloop query="qTest">
    "<cfoutput>#qTest.Image_ID#</cfoutput>": "<cfoutput>#qTest.Image#</cfoutput>",
    </cfloop>
    };

    $("button").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        var src = images[id];

        $("#theImage").attr("src", src).removeClass("hide");

    });

});
</script>

<div id="div1">
    <h2>Display Image</h2>
</div>

    <cfoutput query="qTest">
        <button data-id="#qTest.Image_ID#">#qTest.Account# </button>
    </cfoutput>
    <img id="theImage" class="hide">
</html>
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: http://jquery.com/download/ I used this to download Download the uncompressed, development jQuery 2.0.3 and put it in the folder I have my files in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to wrap the call to `#qTest.image#` in a `<cfoutput></cfoutput>`.  Otherwise, CF wont process it.

`<cfoutput>#qTest.image#</cfoutput>`

Also, jQuery's load() method takes a URL and loads data from the server.  It doesn't insert HTML.

You want something like

`$("#div1").html('<img src="<cfoutput>#qTest.Image#</cfoutput>">');`

- [jQuery Docs for load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)
- [jQuery Docs for html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: Is there a way to auto generate buttons for each image in the database?

Comment: Just loop over the query and create the button: <cfloop query="qTest"><button>Click me</button></cfloop>.  You'll need some kind of identifier like an ID or an HTML5 data-* attribute something like <button data-imgsrc="#qTest.iamge[qTest.currentow]">click me</button> could work.  Then in your click handler you would grab the "imgsrc" data value and use that when creating the <img> tag.

Comment: You need a way to get the image's path.  You could use the ID, if you had the paths referenced somewhere else, for example.

Comment: What if the path to the image are under Image in the database. Slightly confused on this part.

Comment: You are already running a query to get the image's ID and path.  You have this data.  You need them all referenced in the Javascript somewhere to use them.  You could create a Javascript object, for example using the ID as the key and the path as the value.  Then in your click handler, you could determine the ID based on which button was clicked and look the path up in the JS object.  That is just one example, there are many ways you could do this, including looking up the image's source via ajax using the ID.

Comment: OK, just to make it a little more clear... Using no CF here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/seancoyne/MM4Yj/  Now, if you wanted to use CF, you could easily use the query you wrote, loop over it and build the JS object and then loop over it again and create the buttons.  This is just an example, but it seems to do what you are looking for.

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot! Is there a way to link "Remarks from another Table in the same database if they are linked by Image_ID?

Comment: Yep, its called a JOIN.  You would write your query and join the two tables together using the foreign key from one table to the primary key of the other.  As I believe I mentioned in another question of yours, I think you need to slow down a bit and learn the technologies you are trying to use.  Try some simple SQL queries and basic CF first, then move on to getting jQuery to work with them.  The CF WACK books are great at getting you up to speed with some simple SQL and CF examples.  And, also while I have you, please don't use Access.  Use a real DBMS.  MySQL is free and easy to use.

Comment: <cfquery datasource="AccessTest" NAME=qtest>
       SELECT Account, REMARKS
      FROM CommentsDB AS C 
      INNER JOIN PictureDB AS P
  ON C.Image_ID = P.Image_ID
</cfquery>

 <cfoutput query="qTest">
     
       #qTest.Remarks#
      
    </cfoutput>
 Got the join working

Answer (score 1):

.load()  will load from a url info,  but what you are trying to do is a simple .append()  or .html().

That will add the image to your div.